# Why the program keeps applying what is in loop in first case and stops in the second one?

Tags: led, switch, flash

In the first program after removing hand from the button it keeps on, means it keeps applying what is in the loop:

```cpp
int led = 13;
int button = 12;
void setup() {
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
             }
void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(button) == HIGH)
  {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }
             }
```

while in the second one it needs to press the button every time in order to apply what is in the loop,means to flash in this case,

```cpp
int led = 13;
int button = 12;
void setup() {
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
            }
void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(button) == HIGH)
  {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }
           }
```

Why different behavior although the same structure?

The problem is illustrated in this video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5WGvKwJYFY&t=2s

Comment: Looks confusing to me -- `setup()` should only run once per power-on cycle, and so since `value` is only set in `setup()` and not ever changed in `loop()` the behavior should never change after the initial powerup.  Is your circuitry somehow resetting the arduino after each iteration?

Comment: Both of your sketches are missing a "closing bracket", so they won't compile. They do not match the sketches in the video you've provided. Could you tell us what it is you are trying to accomplish? What should the LED do when you press the button? Flash the LED? What happens if you press the button again? Does it turn the flashing LED off?

Comment: no the circuit works fine, i am not trying to accomplish something, it just happened  and i want to know why different in applying the program, i want to understand how  those programs are executed, i thought after pressing the button it should react the same way ,means either  both prorams should apply only when press the button then keep applying or both should stop applying after i press the button, because the both have the same programming structure ,

Comment: in the fist code if i press the button again it does nothing the led is already on and keeps on, in the second code sure if i press the button again it flashes again

Comment: The code you posted does not compile, but it looks like if it did, it will completely ignore changes to button/value in loop() and not produce the effect you show in the video.

Comment: @sumerfattoum, you do not understand ... the code that you posted is not the same as the code in the video

Comment: the code posted is the same as in video if you noticce, it wont apply just cus i didnt copy the end brackts

Comment: u dont understand the idea, in the fist one posted it just instead of just reading it, i just used the name value , i reposted the code exactly as in the video, how ever could you answer why it acts like that in the video ???

Comment: because digitalWrite(led, LOW) turns the led off. but if you don't see it, than stop trying to write programs

Comment: ok, you corrected the code. so, now it is the same as in the video .... the two programs do exactly what you programmed them to do .... the `loop()` function repeats over and over until you press the reset button, or until you turn off the power. ... go through the code step by step. add comments that explain what each command does. you will soon understand why the code works the way it does.

Comment: They are two different codes, i tried to understand step by step but i couldn't that's why I ask , to my knowledge they should react the same way when pressing the button because they are the same structure and the only difference is what the led should do..but they act differently when pressing the button which clearly i don't understand

Answer (score 2):

You read `value` only once ... what do you expected?

In the first sketch, you put the LED ON and never turn it OFF, no matter what.

In the second sketch, you put the LED ON and one second later you turned it OFF. As the `value` doesn't change, it keeps repeating.

You mistake: you read the button in `setup`. You have to read in each `loop` iteration.

```
void loop() {
  value = digitalRead(button);
  if (value == HIGH)
  {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }
```

Comment: did you apply the codes you wrote or think ? i did that firstly , and now i reposted and reedited it so it will read the button in the loop , and still act the same as you see above

Answer (score 1):

This iteration of your code is better.  Now, the difference in behavior is that nothing in the first code ever executes `digitalWrite(led, LOW);`, while each iteration though the second code does.  Therefore the LED remains on forever in code 1, and depends on the button press in code two.

If the behavior you desire is that the code remembers if the button has ever been pressed, latch that event in some state variable, and then in `loop()`, act on the value of the state variable:

```
int led = 13;
int button = 12;
int everHit = 0;
void setup() {
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(button) == HIGH) everHit = 1;
  if (everHit) {
    digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(led, LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```